# Wildcard subdomain being redirected to the wrong domain

Tags: dns, subdomain

I have Linode VPS where I host multiple domains.

Let's say I have

abc.com
def.com

Now I've added a wild card subdomain on def.com like

*.def.com

So that whatever I type as a subdomain (e.g. x.def.com, y.def.com), I'm hoping it will go to "def.com".

But instead of going to "def.com", it's taking me to "abc.com".

Is there anything I've missed?

Comment: What type of record have you added? Was it A or CNAME? What does `dig *.def.com` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using name-based virtual hosts in Apache, the first virtual host to be defined (in the order config files are processed) is the "catch-all" host.

Unless you have virtual hosts for `x.def.com` and `y.def.com` explicitly defined, requests to these hosts will be processed by the "catch-all" host.

Comment: thanks Daniel, is there a way to get around this without explicitly specifying every sub-domain? (I guess I could put def.com first..., but maybe there is a more elegant way?

Comment: Elegant, well... It's possible to accomplish this with a dedicated catch-all host (so as not to disturb the regular content) and mod_rewrite: [Matching Canonical Hostnames](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost). Be warned though, this contains regex trickery.

Comment: You could use some PHP code in the index file of abc.com to perform a permanent redirection when the HTTP header matches Host: def.com